# How do I utilize hashtables to hold words and frequency of use?

Tags: java, hashmap, cpu-word, hashtable, word-frequency

I am so confused right now. I am supposed to write a program that uses a hashtable. The hashtable holds words along with their frequency of use. The class "Word" holds a counter and the string. If the word is already in the table then its frequency increases. I have been researching how to do this but am just lost. I need to be pointed in the right direction. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Hashtable<String, Word> words = new Hashtable<String, Word>();

public void addWord(String s) {
    if (words.containsKey(s) {
        words.get(s).plusOne();
    } else {
        words.put(s, new Word(s));
    }
}
```

This will do it.

Answer (score 3):

Hashtable would be an unusual choice for any new Java code these days. I assume this is some kind of exercise.

I would be slightly concerned by any exercise that hadn't been updated to use newer mechanisms.

HashMap will give you better performance than Hashtable in any single threaded scenario.

But as Emmanuel Bourg [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7910084/how-do-i-utilize-hashtables-to-hold-words-and-frequency-of-use/7910108#7910108), [Bag](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/Bag.html) will do all of this for you without needing the Word class at all: just add String objects to the Bag, and the bag will automatically keep count for you.

Anyway, you're being asked to use a Map, and a map lets you find things quickly by using a key. The key can be any Object, and Strings are very commonly used: they are immutable and have good implementations of hashCode and equals, which make them ideal keys.

The [javadoc for Map](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) talks about how you use maps. Hashtable is one implementation of this interface, though it isn't a particularly good one.

You need a good key to let you find existing Word objects quickly, so that you can increment the counter. While you could make the Word object itself into the key, you would have some work to do: better is to use the String that the Word contains as the key.

You find whether the Word is already in the map by looking for the value object that has the String as its key.

Answer (score 1):

You'd better use a Bag, it keeps the count of each element:

http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/Bag.html

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code should solve your problem

```
  Hashtable <String, Word> myWords = new Hashtable<String, Word>();

  Word w = new Word("test");
  Word w = new Word("anotherTest");

  String inputWord = "test";

  if (myWords.containsKey(inputWord)){
      myWords.get(inputWord).setCounter(myWords.get(inputWord).getCounter+1);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that the class `Word` has a counter and a string, I'd use a `HashMap<String, Word>`.  If your input is an array of `String`s, you can accomplish something like this by using:

```
public Map<String, Word> getWordCount(String[] input) {
    Map<String, Word> output = new HashMap<String, Word>();

    for (String s : input) {
        Word w = output.get(s);
        if (w == null) {
            w = new Word(s, 0);
        }
        w.incrementValue(); // Or w = new Word(s, w.getCount() + 1) if you have no such function
        output.put(s, w);
    }

    return output;
```

}